# Bouncing Ball Game in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am helping my little sister to help her code a bouncing ball game in python.

The aim of the game is to hit two targets as many times as you can to earn the highest score. Every time the ball hits Target 1 and Target 2 you earn 10 points, and 30 points, respectively.

So far we have managed to code this:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

count = 0
lost = False

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, paddle2, target1, target2, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle
        self.paddle2 = paddle2
        self.target1 = target1
        self.target2 = target2
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 15, 15, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 150, 200)
        starts= [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)
        self.x = starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.hit_bottom=False

    def hit_paddle(self,pos):
        paddle_pos=self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
                return True
            return False

    def hit_paddle2(self,pos):
        paddle2_pos=self.canvas.coords(self.paddle2.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle2_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle2_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle2_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle2_pos[3]:
                return True
            return False

    def hit_target1(self,pos):
        target1_pos=self.canvas.coords(self.target1.id)
        if pos[2] >= target1_pos[0] and pos[0] <= target1_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= target1_pos[1] and pos[3] <= target1_pos[3]:
                return True
            return False

    def hit_target2(self,pos):
        target2_pos=self.canvas.coords(self.target2.id)
        if pos[2] >= target2_pos[0] and pos[0] <= target2_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= target2_pos[1] and pos[3] <= target2_pos[3]:
                return True
            return False

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = 3
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.hit_bottom=True
        if self.hit_paddle(pos)==True:
            self.y=-3
        if self.hit_paddle2(pos)==True:
            self.y=3
        if self.hit_target1(pos)==True:
            self.y=-3
        if self.hit_target2(pos)==True:
            self.y=-3
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3
        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 3

            global count
            count +=1
            score()   
        if pos[3] <= self.canvas_height:
            self.canvas.after(10, self.draw)
        else:
            self.canvas.move(self.id, 150, 200)
            game_over()
            global lost
            lost = True

class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 50, 10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 150, 300)
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-Left>", self.move_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-Right>", self.move_right)

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0

    def move_left(self, evt):
            self.x = -2

    def move_right(self, evt):
            self.x = 2

class Paddle2:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 50, 10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 0, 300)
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-a>", self.move_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-d>", self.move_right)

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0

    def move_left(self, evt):
            self.x = -2

    def move_right(self, evt):
            self.x = 2

class Target1:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 35, 35, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 40, 120)
        self.x = 0

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)

class Target2:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 70, 70, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 100, 40)
        self.x = 0

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)

def start_game(event):
    global lost, count, ball
    if lost==True:
        ball=Ball(canvas,paddle,paddle2, target1, target2, "red")
    lost = False    
    count = 0
    score()
    canvas.itemconfig(game, text=" ")

def score():
    canvas.itemconfig(score_now, text="score: " + str(count))

def game_over():
    canvas.itemconfig(game, text="Game over :(")

tk = Tk()
tk.title("Guller's Cool Game")
tk.resizable(0,0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", -1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=200, height=400, bd=0,highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()

paddle = Paddle(canvas, "red")
paddle2=Paddle2(canvas, "black")
target1=Target1(canvas, "yellow")
target2=Target2(canvas, "green")
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, paddle2, target1, target2, "blue")
score_now = canvas.create_text(155, 10, text="score: " + str(count), fill = "red", font=("Tahoma", 12))
game = canvas.create_text(100, 200, text=" ", fill="red", font=("Tahoma", 16))

while 1:
    if ball.hit_bottom==False:
        ball.draw()
        paddle.draw()
        paddle2.draw()
        target1.draw()
        target2.draw()
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

How can we get the above code to work properly so that every time the ball hits target1 and target2 you get 10 points and 30 points, respectively?

Also, how can I make it so that you get a message which says "press any key to start" to start the game...

Many thanks for your time and help.

Mesut

Comment: lol that plays so fast ... how can you tell what you hit visually? you really shoudl slow down the update significantly ... it also seems to go off the side of the screen...

Comment: That's a lot of code duplication!

Comment: thanks, as i am very new to python that's the difficult bit where i am struggling.  if i remove the stuff which does the counting it works (i still have one or two issues tho)